# Access 2003 conditional formatting and field with NULL value not return NULL

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

The field is taken from the table and is the source of data for the textbox, in which I want to apply conditional formatting. Almost always it is `NULL`. The expression for the conditional formatting:

```
Not IsNull ([duedate])
```

Always returns true, I do not understand why. Field `[duedate]` belongs to the parent form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the length also along with IsNull like

```
Len(Field) = 0
```